# Display Bootstrap alert prior to sql call

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to display a bootstrap alert:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" id="slow_loading_data">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Retrieving a large quantity of data, please wait.
</div>
```

I want this to immediately display prior to the remainder of the PHP code running.  I have an SQL statement that is retrieving over 5000 records from a MySQL database, so I want the user to be aware that the page is loading.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . dbname_bowl . ".ball_model";
try {
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    while($data = $query->fetch()) {
        $modelID = $data['modelID'];
        $model[$modelID]['name'] = $data['name'];
    }
        $query->closeCursor();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error_message = 'There was an error processing your request. Page aborted. Please contact the System Administrator with Date & Time of your error. (' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) . ")";
        $application->enqueueMessage(JText::_($error_message), 'error');
        return;
    }
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is flush the output to the screen, before the loop. You can achieve this by using the [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) & [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) methods of PHP

So try the following:

Right after `<?php` (or right after `session_start()`, if you have that), add the following line:

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
```

This will *turn on your output buffer*. Read/lean more on [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Then, right before `$sql = ...` bit, add the following:

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

**What [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) does is:**

> Flush (send) the output buffer

**What [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) method does is:**

> Flush system output buffer

if that does not work, add the following before `ob_flush()`:

```
echo str_pad("", 4096);
```

(by adding the above `echo`, you are tricking it into thinking that it *has* enough data to perform the flush)

One more thing to note, per comment by [dermeister](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314) on the PHP manual page of `ob_flush`--

> some problems with ob_flush() and flush() could be resolved by defining content type header :

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: That still does not seem to be working.  It still will not show any content until it retrieves all the database records.

Comment: @CharlesWilkinsIV do you have proper `Content-type` header? See my edited answer. Also, check out the `ob_start` line that I have added to the answer... If this is still an issue, then you will need to specify more details about your setup!

Comment: I decided to go a different route as the page took too long to load the data.   I was using Datatables so I went with the server side version and it now loads quick enough that I don't need to do this.    I did try your suggestion though and it did not work for me.